# Add multiple tokens into DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization in HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

The API I'm calling from my ASP.NET Web API app requires two tokens i.e. `accessToken` and `userToken`.

The following code is not working because it takes only the second token, not both. Looks like the second line is over-writing the first one.

How do I add multiple tokens to my request header?

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("APIAccessToken", "token1");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("UserToken", "token2");
```

UPDATE:
Here's the way I set this up and it's not working. Basically, my API calls seem to go nowhere. I get no errors. Just no response.

First, I have the `HttpClientAccessor` that looks like this:

```
public static class HttpClientAccessor
{
    private static Lazy<HttpClient> client = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => new HttpClient());

    public static HttpClient HttpClient
    {
       get
         {
             client.Value.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.someurl.com");
             client.Value.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
             client.Value.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));     

             client.Value.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("APIAccessToken", "token1");
             client.Value.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("UserToken", "token2");

             return client.Value;
           }
     }
}
```

I then have my ApiClient that will perform my API calls which looks like this:

```
public class MyApiClient
{
    HttpClient _client;

    public MyApiClient()
    {
        _client = HttpClientAccessor.HttpClient;
    }

    public async Task Get()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync("/myendpoint"); // This is where it gets lost
            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            var error = e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my controller action:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   private readonly MyApiClient _client;

   public MyController()
   {
      _client = new MyApiClient();
   }

   public IActionResult SomeAction()
   {
       _client.Get().Wait();
   }
}
```

Comment: Has the API docs indicated how the tokens are to be passed with the request?which headers they are suppose to use?

Comment: I think you probably just need to add them as normal headers

Comment: It simply says: Add the generated tokens to the request headers "APIAccessToken" and "UserToken"

Comment: Ok as I suspected. You are using the wrong default header. Hold on

Comment: Here's a link to their documentation: http://help.workamajig.com/api-overview

Comment: You should only add it once when you were initializing the client.

Comment: Quick question. are those values expected to change for the life cycle of the application?

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I'm initializing the HttpCient in the constructor and that's where I'm adding the tokens.

Comment: No. They're generated through their portal and stay the same till we decide to generate new ones.

Comment: Move that code to inside `HttpClientAccessor`

Comment: Weirdest thing! I moved the code inside the `HttpClientAccessor` and the tokens are still there twice. My API call is also going nowhere. No error. Just no response.

Comment: I'm posting all the code so you can see the big picture.

Comment: Ok you need to step through your code and see where you are setting that header.

Comment: Any updates on progress?

Comment: I just updated the original post and pasted all the code involved in the process. Clearly, the way I set this is up isn't right. Not sure where though.

Comment: Every time you called `HttpClientAccessor.HttpClient` it added the default headers. Move the assignment of those defaults into the value factory of the client. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the standard authorization header with custom headers

According to the linked documentation

> ## Request Header
>
> Add the generated tokens to the request headers "APIAccessToken" and "UserToken"
>
> Example Request
>
> ```
> APIAccessToken: zjhVgRIvcZItU8sCNjLn+0V56bJR8UOKOTDYeLTa43eQX9eynX90QntWtINDjLaRjAyOPgrWdrGK12xPaOdDZQ==
> UserToken: 5sb8Wf94B0g3n4RGOqkBdPfX+wr2pmBTegIK73S3h7uL8EzU6cjsnJ0+B6vt5iqn0q+jkZgN+gMRU4Y5+2AaXw==
> ```

To get headers like above, add them to the client like below

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("APIAccessToken", "token1");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("UserToken", "token2");
```

Based on shown update, the client is adding the headers every time the client is called. This should be in the value factory of the lazy client.

```
public static class HttpClientAccessor {
   
    public static Func<HttpClient> ValueFactory = () => {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://someApiUrl");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("APIAccessToken", "token1");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("UserToken", "token2");
        return client;
    };

    private static Lazy<HttpClient> client = new Lazy<HttpClient>(ValueFactory);

    public static HttpClient HttpClient {
        get {
            return client.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

The controller action also needs to be refactored to avoid deadlocks because of the mixing of async and blocking calls like `.Wait()` or `.Result`.

```
public class MyController : Controller {
   private readonly MyApiClient _client;

   public MyController() {
      _client = new MyApiClient();
   }

   public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction() {
       await _client.Get();
       
       //... code removed for brevity
   }
}
```